# Webmasters' 'Greatest Hits' Questions

Tags: discussion, blog

With the new blog post by [Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/), he reveals a nice little feature of the *greatest hits* from every site on SE. In this, he suggests that every site should monitor, clean and flag the greatest hits questions so we can keep up relevancy and quality.

I know we've discussed what should and shouldn't be asked on the site, but exactly **what questions do we want representing our site to everyone else**?

Comment: I thought that the greatest hits were based off of an algorithm.

Comment: They are based off of an algorithm (it's detailed in a box on the right sidebar) however,  a [number](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/263/linguistics-greatest-hits) of [other](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/our-greatest-hits) [sites](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2671/how-can-we-improve-the-greatest-hits-of-our-site) are working to clean up their `greatest-hits` pages. It might be something for this site to consider? :D

Comment: There's ways for us to take out what is on the greatest-hits page, therefore allowing us to choose what we would like representing our site. In any case, we should all take a careful look at what is already up there and edit them to provide the best look of Pro Webmasters.

Comment: for those who want a link: it's located here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits

Answer (score 1):

Based off of what other sites are doing, what people should do is edit questions if they can improve, and flag them if they aren't good questions.

Comment: The [question highlighter](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/637/what-should-we-do-about-low-quality-nonspecific-questions) script appears to work on this page. I'm working through the first page now and will set reminders to keep working through it - your suggested edits will continue to receive prompt moderator attention :)

Comment: @danlefree I'm working towards 2000 rep: I should get the edit privilege soon